# Login code sample which has been hacked via SQL Injection, although mysql_real_escape_string...

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, sql-injection

I use CodeIgniter, and having trouble with hacking. Is it possible to make SQL Injection to the login code below:

```
    function process_login()
{
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('username'));    
    $password  = mysql_real_escape_string(MD5($this->input->post('password')));

    //Check user table
    $query = $this->db->getwhere('users', array('username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password));

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        // success login data
```

Am I using the  `mysql_real_escape_string` wrong, or what?

Comment: use htmlentities after real_escape_string and better make data in binary format

Comment: How do you know you’ve been hacked via SQL Injection?

Comment: Depends on the attack. If the hacker gained unauthorized access to an account, you might hear complaints from the victim, but otherwise you may never know. If the hacker altered database contents, or dropped tables altogether, you'll notice when your system stops working.

Comment: The best practice for PHP development is to either use mysqli or PDO. They take parameters, which are sent separately from the query string, and have a lot of organizational and often performance benefits over old-school PHP code.

Answer (score 7):

No what have posted is not probably not vulnerable to sql injection.  Although getwhere() could be doing a stripslashes(),  I'm not sure.

Its likely that if there was SQL Injection that it is in another part of your application.  The attacker could use this vulnerability to obtain your **extremely weak** md5() hash,  crack it,  and then login.  Use any member of the sha2 family,  sha-256 is a great choice.

If your site has been defaced then I seriously doubt that it is sql injection.   Its difficult to automate the exploitation of sql injection to deface websites,  but it is possible.  I would make sure that all libraries and installed applications are fully updated.  Especially if you have a CMS or forum.  You could run an [OpenVAS](http://www.openvas.org/) scan against your site to see if it finds any old software.

Comment: Actually, you should use PBKDF2 - Explenation plus code example: http://www.itnewb.com/v/Encrypting-Passwords-with-PHP-for-Storage-Using-the-RSA-PBKDF2-Standard

Comment: @Frits van Campen if its too heavy for an attacker to lift then its too heavy for your servers.

Comment: PBKDF2 is designed especially for this purpose. sha-256 is not. I'm no crypto-pro but I'm willing to trust their word on it. There was an article about this on /. recently. http://ask.slashdot.org/story/11/06/05/0135206/Ask-Slashdot-Is-SHA-512-the-Way-To-Go

Comment: @Frits van Campen  A [Hidden salt](http://blog.mozilla.com/webappsec/2011/05/10/sha-512-w-per-user-salts-is-not-enough/) is far more effective than key strengthening for web applications,  which is the domain that we are discussing.  Encrypted file systems often make use of PBKDF2,  because they have no choice.

Comment: Do they have to be mutually exclusive? I don't think so. I do like the idea of a hidden salt as it prevents against MySQL leaks. In most cases though you don't know the hashing algorithm (unlike the link you posted). Even adding a static salt would foil that.

Comment: @Frits van Campen i have no idea what a "mysql leak" is,  but SQL Injection is a very common in all web application platforms and its the main reason why we hash passwords.  Obscuring the hashing algorithm is (in)"security though obscurity",  which isn't secure at all.

Comment: @rook wouldn't bcrypt be a better option than SHA family in this case (as mentioned in your linked hidden salts article)?

Comment: @Rory McCune  and  Frits van Campen bcrypt is slow,  and thats why its useful for key strengthening.   If you have a very large hidden salt then you don't have to burn time with key strengthening and you are forcing the attacker to make a HUGE number of guesses (a larger number than we have a word for) without wasting your server's resources.  So yes you can use them together and it would be multiplicative,  but already way out of reach with a hidden salt of 40 bytes or so.

Comment: @rook, true but "hidden" salt predicates the idea that the attacker will have access to the database and not the filesystem (which is where the hidden salt will be stored), which in many threat scenarios won't hold true.  bcrypt works regardless.  I do like the idea of hidden salts, but it seems a bit brittle as filesystem access essentially destroys its usefulness

Comment: @Rory McCune  It depends how its implemented.   By just having two vulnerabilities,  sql injection and directory traversal you raise the bar because of "Security in layers".  However Mozilla is using a setuid root binary to obtain the salt,  so you would need shell access in order to obtain the key which is used to encrypt salts and that point its game over anyway.

Answer (score 5):

## Database

Judging by your code I see you're **not** using the lastest CI version (2.0.2 as of 06/12).

As stated in the [changelog](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html) the `getwhere()` function (which is now called `get_where()`) has been abandoned as for version 2.0. 
 As for everty application out there you're strongly suggested to upgrade your current version, as there has been a lot of bugfixes in the meantime and you should always rely on the safest version available.

[mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) usually is considered 'enough' to give a good level of safety in your queries, but as it happend to its predecessor (mysql_escape_string) it isn't 100% safe against all kind of attack, so relying interely on that is not the best practice around. Although safe, there are still attacks that can go past this filter.
Check, among the many, [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353666/php-is-mysql-real-escape-string-sufficient-for-cleaning-user-input) for further information about this.

**In codeignier:**
If you were developing your custom application, I'd suggest you to at least use the [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extensions or, better yet, the [PDO](http://it.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) class; **prepared statements** are undoubtely safest and should be favoured over everything else.

But we are in the framework context, and Codeigniter comes with 3 great ways of safely querying your database, applying the right tool to the right input without you having to worry about that. I'm talking about [query bindings and manual escaping with $this->db->escape() family](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html) and the [Active Record Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) 
You can find examples of use at the urls I just linked, or read the answers from other peers here, so I won't go into the details of each procedure in this post.

## Password

Regarding your password, as already stated by other users, `md5()` is a now flawed hashing alghoritm. There are rainbow tables out there that can crack your md5 password in a relatively short amount of time, so you're better off with higher security level hashing algorhytms, like [sha1()](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) or [sha256, sha512, and other](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)

**In codeigniter:**
Codeigniter comes with a [security helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/security_helper.html) class, which provides you with a handy function, `do_hash()` (might be `dohash()` in your older installation), which can be given the hashing alg. as paramter (currently I think it supports only md5 and sha1) and defaults to sha1() anyway.

## Other observations

I'm not entirely clear on why you blame your login for your SQL injections. Are those the only 2 forms in your whole application? 
 You dind't provide the info to tell if you use $_GET parameters or you follow the native URI segmentation, but I believe you're doing like this so I assume you're safe from this point of view. 
You should make sure then that there's no other input form in your website which contains input going into the database, otherwise you can secure your login how much you want, but someone could penetrate through a backdoor and read from there your database table and get log into your website in a "legitimate" way.

Moreover, there can be other source of intrusion, like a compromized cookie for example. As a piece of advice, whenever you choose to use a framework (and you're doing yourself a bigger favour than developing from scratch and all by yourself) you should tend to use MOST of its features, expecially when it comes down to security. It's a huge and very delicate question, so you **MUST** give this topic your top priority, and a well developed framework, with a huge community and frequent updates is the closest to safety you can get. 
 Therefore, you're adviced to *update* your CI installation (guides can be found [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrading.html) in their manual. Choose your version and follow the instruction), always use the top tools you're given for each task, and don't think that barring your door will make you safe from an intrusion from your windows. Always check thoroughly and investigate all possibile causes.

**Late Addendum:** Don't forget XSS, CSRF, session fixations, and other hot security problems.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615792/does-code-igniter-automatically-prevent-sql-injection) old SO question.
I would use:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '?' AND password= '?'";
$dbResult = $this->db->query($sql, array($this->input->post('username')),array($this->input->post('password')));
```

Comment: so, no need to make mysql_real_escape_string at this way?

Comment: Nope if you use query bindings on query() method.
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

Answer (score 3):

If this is an ongoing hack, then seriously consider putting some logging in place to record the username/password in a file somewhere. If it is an sql injection via this login snippet, then it would show up in this new log file somewhere. And while you're at it, if you can, log the generated SQL query as well.

In any case, remember that mysql_real_escape_string() only covers mysql's metacharacters: single-quote, double-quote, semi-colon, etc... It is still entirely possible to hack the login function via mangling of a boolean parameter. Impossible to say if your "getwhere" function is vulnerable, but consider the case where the submitted password is "xyz OR (1=1)". The generated query might end looking something like

```
 SELECT id FROM users WHERE users=someusername AND password=xyz OR (1=1);
```

Perfectly valid query, and has also passed through mysql_real_escape_string intact because it didn't contain any of the critical metacharacters.

Comment: the generated query will have single quotes around the someusername and xyz strings,so in this case no harm

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that Active Records will properly escape the values for you. So, with `$query = $this->db->getwhere()` you do NOT need to use `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

But, you should always use some sort of Controller validation. In particular, you can limit the username and password to certain characters via a regular expression. This is always suggested.

Furthermore, if you are getting hit with typical attacks often then look into using PHPIDS. It's an Intrusion Detection System that will help you prevent the attacks from actually causing any damage, as you can thrown an error or notice of some sort.

You may also wish to view this tutorial on Security issues.
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-security/

Answer (score 1):

If all your functions and accessors do what their names seem to suggest, then this script is not vulnerable to SQL Injection.

As for whether you are using mysql_real_escape_string properly... yes and no. Yes, you have the right idea, but you're actually using it excessively. If you MD5 the password, then that input is now clean and can't be used for injection, so the mysql_real_escape_string call is superfluous. So this would be fine:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('username'));    
$password  = MD5($this->input->post('password'));
```

As previously mentioned, MD5 is a rather weak hash algorithm by itself. Look into SHA and salting a hash.

To counter a previous answer posted, if a user inputs "xyz OR (1=1)" as a password, that poses absolutely no threat to his script for two reasons.

1) MD5 hashing would convert that to a harmless hash (e.g. 'd131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c'), making the query something along the lines of `SELECT id FROM users WHERE users='username' AND password='d131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c';`

2) mysql_real_escape_string prevents 'string' injections, that is injections that would require a single or double quote to break out of the expected SQL query, but does not prevent (for example) injection with numerical input, which you would need to use type-casting to block.

Everything is really contingent on your "$this->db->getwhere" call. If that just builds the query normally without doing anything funky (like stripping quotes, or treating strings as integers [which would throw an error anyway], etc) you are simply not vulnerable in this script. If you could give more details on the 'type' of hacking you've experienced, we could probably give you some guidance where to look. Were you defaced?

I haven't played with CodeIgnitor, but expect that their built in input/database functions wouldn't do anything weird like that - so unless you edited the getwhere function yourself, you're probably fine in this particular spot.

Comment: Actually, you should use PBKDF2 - Explenation plus code example: http://www.itnewb.com/v/Encrypting-Passwords-with-PHP-for-Storage-Using-the-RSA-PBKDF2-Standard

Comment: bcrypt is another good option for password storage http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: Never argue that a certain variable "is safe because of it's possible content". If you do, then you must inspect every possible variable whether or not it actually needs escaping, and all your code looks unsafe at first because half of the escaping seems to be missing. So never argue that something does not need escaping - **always** escape!

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is not vulnerable for SQL injection, but you should never put passwords into queries, not even hashed, because you cannot be sure if the query is saved to the server's log or not, and you usually don't have control about who can have access to that.

Query/load the user's record by username, and then compare the hash of the password in $_POST to that.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to resistant to injection attacks. You are taking md5 of password field which leaves out any injection attack on that field. The vulnerable field is username which you are escaping anyhow. Are you sure that this is an injection attack?

Is there any other field like access_token fields passed along to prevent CSRF

Following are probable causes of strange behavior:

- You are using mysqli driver in database config and escaping string according to mysql lib. Try providing `$this->db->conn_id` as second parameter to `mysql_real_escape_string` and check your php logs for warnings.
- mysql_real_escape_string needs `connection link identifier` as second parameter. If you don't provide it you will experience strange behavior. I have suffered this with codeigniter. In my case `mysql_real_escape_string` was returning empty strings. If the case is same with you, check that you don't have empty passwords and usernames in your users table (very less probable).