# CodeIgniter - numbers in sql query are masked with ``

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i'm using CodeIgniter for developing a community board. As I'm using nested sets to get a nested forum hierarchy, I have to run a lot of queries such as:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `forums` WHERE 1 BETWEEN `lft` AND `rgt`
```

My problem: CodeIgniter is replacing the "1" by "`1`" because the "1" is recognized as a column name. Of course, the query does not work any more.

Is there a way to get it working?

thx in advance

Comment: Show your code please, are you using `->query` or AR Classes ?

Comment: could we see the actual `query()` call in your PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you need?

$this->db->select() accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound select statement. you can try if query does that too. 
also there is this question :
[Does CodeIgniter automatically prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615792/does-code-igniter-automatically-prevent-sql-injection)

cheers