# PHP/mysql - My timestamp does not like to be in a greater than (>) statement

Tags: php, mysql, database, timestamp

I've got a timestamp in my database with the value: `2011-10-05 16:06:48` which is bigger than the `$start` variable (`2011-10-04 13:02:34`) I have defined yet when I run the query I get an error message.

```
function getgeneration() {

$period = '1 month';
$siteid = 1;
$start = '2011-10-04 13:02:34';

$value = $this->GetOffset();

$this->db->select("esolar + $value AS Esolar")
     ->from('calcdata')
     ->where('siteid', $siteid)
     ->where("time > $start");
$query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
$Esolar1 = $query[0]['Esolar'];
echo $Esolar1;
return $Esolar1;

}
```

> ```
> A Database Error Occurred
> ```
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '13:02:34' at line 4
>
> SELECT esolar + 3 AS Esolar FROM (calcdata) WHERE `siteid` = 1 AND
>   `time` > 2011-10-04 13:02:34
>
> Filename: /var/www/test/models/blog_model.php
>
> Line Number: 220

Is this a common problem with timestamps?

Comment: just quote the value, you're passing it as a string.

Comment: Consult the database manual of your framework about parametrized queries. You are probably using Codeigniter: [Does Code Igniter automatically prevent SQL injection?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1615792/367456)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you need to put quotes around the timestamp such as:

```
SELECT esolar + 3 AS Esolar FROM (calcdata) WHERE siteid = '1' AND time > '2011-10-04 13:02:34'
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you just need to change

```
->where("time > $start");
```

in

```
->where("time > '$start'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the timestamp in single or double quotes. They are strings.