# How to perform a php function within a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
function SearchMembers()
{
    // grab user input
    //$my_gender = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('my_gender'));
    $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('looking_for_gender'));
    $age_from = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('age_from'));
    $age_to = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('age_to'));
    $member_postcode = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('postcode'));
    $member_distance = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('distance'));                               

    // Prep the query

    $this->db->where('Gender', $looking_for_gender);
    $this->db->where('Age >=', $age_from);
    $this->db->where('Age <=', $age_to);
    $miles =  $this->search_form_model->distCalc('postcode',$member_postcode);
    $this->db->where($miles < $member_distance);
    // Run the query
    $query = $this->db->get('member');
    // Let's check if there are any results

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            return $query->result();
        }

        // If the previous process did not validate
        // then return false.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope someone can help. I'm performing a distance check between two postcodes in miles, and add all the ones that are less than distance to the result.

Previously all I have done is iterated through all postcodes that match gender and age then done a miles less than distance check and but the results in a json array, now a want to perform it within the mysql query if possible ideally using codeigniter framework. many thanks

Comment: That `return` will just exit the function at the first iteration

Comment: There is no function at the moment to exit from :-)

Comment: MySQL cannot execute PHP code. You can build a UDF in mysql to do that sort of thing, but it won't be in PHP. Your sole option, with no changes to the setup, is to fetch all data to php and then apply filters there, which will be very inefficient if your filter tends to reject most of the results.

Comment: It will both `return` on the first iteration, AND return the second result, not the first.  Are you sure that is how you want the function to work?

Comment: I just get the following output ,SELECT * FROM (`member`) WHERE `Gender` = 'female' AND `Age` >= '18' AND `Age` <= '55' AND `0` IS NULL  I'm gathering this is because the distCalc is not working like i hoped.

Comment: Please edit your question - you appear to have missed half the class and method(function) off the start of your code

Comment: Added the rest of the function, I know the distCalc works fine when previously used.

Comment: Do you have coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, use bound paramaters instead of XSS clean:

See [Does CodeIgniter automatically prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615792/does-code-igniter-automatically-prevent-sql-injection)

Assuming you have the longitude and latitude, you can add this to select the distance

```
$this->db->select("
            Gender,Age, --etc.
            (
                (
                    ACOS(
                          SIN($lat * PI() / 180) 
                        * SIN(`lat` * PI() / 180) 
                        + COS($lat * PI() / 180) 
                        * COS(`lat` * PI() / 180) 
                        * COS(($lon - `lon`) 
                        * PI() / 180)) 
                        * 180 / PI()
                ) * 60 * 1.1515
            ) AS distance            
        ");
```

You will also need an `order by` to sort, and a `having` to only return values within the distance..

```
$this->db->order_by('distance');
$this->db->having('distance <= '.$member_distance.' OR postcode='.$member_postcode);
```