# Codeigniter MySQL security, htmlspecialcharacters & mysql_real_escape_string?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, security, special-characters

I've been reading a lot about database security and using htmlspecialcharacters() and mysql_real_escape_string.

Is this necessary to use these functions with codeigniter or does it handle this automatically?  e.g.

```
$this->db->select('*', FALSE);
$this->db->where('published', 'yes');
$query = $this->db->get('my_table');
$results = $query->result_array()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Code Igniter automatically prevent SQL injection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615792/does-code-igniter-automatically-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: From the docs: "the values are escaped automatically by the system." http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to worry about escaping your text as long as you use active records.