# What are the best ways to prevent SQLInjection in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-injection

I am new to the codeigniter framework and im makeing a few queries my question is what is the best way to keep my queries safe. Should I use `mysql_real_escape_string` or is there some better way.
I use the following code for my inserts:

```
    function createCustomer($data){
    $this->firstname    = $data['firstname'];
    $this->lastname     = $data['surname1'].' '.$data['surname2'];
    $this->address      = $data['adres'];
    $this->zipcode      = $data['zipcode'];
    $this->mail         = $data['mail'];
    $this->phonenumber  = $data['phonenumber'];

    $this->db->insert('Klant',$this);

    //Check if the change was succesfull
    return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1) ? false : true;
}
```

And the following code for gets:

```
    function getUserByName($firstname, $lastname){
       $query = $this->db->get_where('Customer', array('firstname' => $firstname, 'lastname' => $lastname));
    return $query->result();
}
```

What would be the best way to prevent sql injection? Any tips are welcome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615792/does-code-igniter-automatically-prevent-sql-injection And no, you DON'T use mysql_*() functions. They're obsolete and deprecated.

Comment: I missed that question, I shall read over it now thank you for linking. I will keep that in mind

Comment: It's already built into the framework.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way to do is
Open the file  config.php
file location  application/config

make the following code to true

```js
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Global XSS Filtering
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Determines whether the XSS filter is always active when GET, POST or
  | COOKIE data is encountered
  |
 */
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```

to

```js
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Global XSS Filtering
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Determines whether the XSS filter is always active when GET, POST or
  | COOKIE data is encountered
  |
 */
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

You do not to do anything more for prevent sql injection and cross site scripting.

Comment: That is a quick fix! Is there no need to sanitize my queries?

Comment: NOTE:  The `global_xss_filtering` setting has been deprecated in CodeIgniter version 3

Comment: So since they deprecated it should I not use it? Is there something else you'd reccomend?

Comment: This doesn't do anything at all in relation to preventing SQL injection. The answer is outright wrong.