# codeigniter escaping queries

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

What's up with this logic:

I have a book title called "Day and Night"

```
$this->db->select('b.Book_Name,Author');
$this->db->from('Books b');
$this->db->where('Book_Name',$book['Book_Name']);
$query = $this->db->get();

if($query->num_rows() > 0 ) 
    {
     $arr['by_genre'] = $query->result_array();
    }
```

0 results,

however if I change the name to "Day an Night" I get

```
  ['Book_Name'=>'Day an Night', 
     'Author'=>'Gene Night',  
     'ISBN'=> '124BA123', ..]
```

so my question is how do i tell my query to escape the "and" treating it as a string and not a condition.

Comment: And what is $book['Book_Name'] ? Are you sure that its correct and set

Comment: $book['Book_Name'] is the string 'Day and Night'

Comment: Can you show your full function..

Comment: I'd use a parameterized query. I haven't worked with codeigniter but here's a thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615792/does-codeigniter-automatically-prevent-sql-injection.

Comment: @chris85 doesn't using the active record class (as i'm doing) automatically escape my queries?

Comment: I don't know as I stated I don't (and havent ever) used code igniter. I would use a parameterized query though because then you dont have to worry about escaping.

Comment: @chris85 that worked but im pretty sure that is not the intended result of the active record class.

Comment: Can't offer any advise on that sorry; I think that'd be a separate question, or update this one to be more specific to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in CodeIgniter 3.0.0 and 3.0.1. It was fixed in version 3.0.2, and the current stable version is 3.0.3 ...

All you need to do is update your CI setup.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with active record class or intended use?

Below query solves the problem: (allows *and* in the book name)

```
$sql = "SELECT b.Book_Name,author
        FROM Books b WHERE b.CARD_NAME = ?";

$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($book['Book_Name']));
```

Vs:  does not allow *and* in the book name.

```
$this->db->select('b.Book_Name,Author');
$this->db->from('Books b');
$this->db->where('Book_Name',$book['Book_Name']);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: It's called "Query Builder" in CI3, not active record.