# Query Builder Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I this mysql query

```
SELECT project.title project_title, category.category, project_details.description description, SUM(project_details.quantity) total_quantity, project_details.unit, SUM(project_details.price) total_price, SUM(project_details.jan) total_jan, SUM(project_details.feb) total_feb, SUM(project_details.mar) total_mar, SUM(project_details.apr) total_apr, SUM(project_details.may) total_may, SUM(project_details.jun) total_jun, SUM(project_details.jul) total_jul, SUM(project_details.aug) total_aug, SUM(project_details.sep) total_sep, SUM(project_details.oct) total_oct, SUM(project_details.nov) total_nov, SUM(project_details.dec) total_dec
FROM project_details
JOIN project ON project_details.project_id = project.id
JOIN category ON project_details.category_id = category.id
JOIN user ON project.user_id = user.id
RIGHT JOIN office ON user.office_id = office.id
WHERE EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT t1.id id1, t2.id id2, t3.id id3, t4.id id4, t5.id id5
        FROM user t1
        LEFT JOIN user t2 ON t2.reports_to = t1.id
        LEFT JOIN user t3 ON t3.reports_to = t2.id
        LEFT JOIN user t4 ON t4.reports_to = t3.id
        LEFT JOIN user t5 ON t5.reports_to = t4.id
        WHERE t1.id = 81
    )
    AND project.approval_status = 22 AND project.reason_for_rejection IS NULL
GROUP BY project.id, project_details.description
ORDER BY project_details.category_id
```

However I cannot find any documentation in Codeigniter 3.0 where I can find `WHERE EXISTS`. I already checked this  https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html  but there are non.

This is my code right now

```
$this->db->select('project.title project_title, category.category, project_details.description description, SUM(project_details.quantity) total_quantity, project_details.unit, SUM(project_details.price) total_price, SUM(project_details.jan) total_jan, SUM(project_details.feb) total_feb, SUM(project_details.mar) total_mar, SUM(project_details.apr) total_apr, SUM(project_details.may) total_may, SUM(project_details.jun) total_jun, SUM(project_details.jul) total_jul, SUM(project_details.aug) total_aug, SUM(project_details.sep) total_sep, SUM(project_details.oct) total_oct, SUM(project_details.nov) total_nov, SUM(project_details.dec) total_dec');
$this->db->from('project_details');
$this->db->join('project', 'project_details.project_id = project.id');
$this->db->join('category', 'project_details.category_id = category.id');
$this->db->join('user', 'project.user_id = user.id');
$this->db->join('office', 'user.office_id = office.id', 'right');
// THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO PUT THE WHERE EXISTS
$this->db->where('project.approval_status', $user_id);
$this->db->where('project.reason_for_rejection IS NULL', NULL, TRUE);
$this->db->group_by('project.id');
$this->db->group_by('project_details.description');
$this->db->order_by('project_details.category_id');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Can someone please help how can I achieve this in codeigniter? Advanced thanks.

Comment: have you tried `$query = $this->db->query('your large query');` ?

Comment: Isn't it that `$this->db->query('query')` is susceptible for SQL injections?

Comment: you should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615792/does-codeigniter-automatically-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: I see thanks for the answer. I will use this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a really large query, or the is no built-in function on the query builder made for your purpose you can always use:

```
$query = $this->db->query('your large query');
```

You also should be aware of the injections so you should also read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615792/does-codeigniter-automatically-prevent-sql-injection)

This explains pretty well how to use `$this->db->query` method against sql injections.

Hope this helps