# Write query with subquery in CodeIgniter Query Builder?

Tags: php, codeigniter, query-builder

I have the following query which has an issue with Query Builder.

```sql
SELECT Sum(TEMP.total) AS total_amount
FROM   (SELECT Ifnull(t3.amount, t1.amount) AS total
        FROM   table1 AS t1
               LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
                      ON t2.class = t1.class
               LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3
                      ON t3.student = t2.student
                         AND t3.type = t1.type) AS TEMP
```

Is there any way to do it with Query Builder? I'm currently using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36081503/query-builder-codeigniter-3) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DO NOT USE `get()` followed by `last_query()` because `get()` will actually run the query on database.**

Instead, use `get_compiled_select()` that will returns the query without running it.

```
$this->db->select('IFNULL(t3.amount, t1.amount) as total');
$this->db->from('table1 as t1');
$this->db->join('table2 as t2', 't2.class = t1.class', 'LEFT');
$this->db->join('table3 as t3', 't3.student = t2.student AND t3.type = t1.type', 'LEFT');
$subquery = $this->db->get_compiled_select();


$this->db->select('SUM(TEMP.total) as total_amount');
$this->db->from('('.$subquery.') as TEMP');
$result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

By default `get_compiled_select()` will reset the query builder.

[See the docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=query%20builder#CI_DB_query_builder::get).

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check with this, hope will help you

```
$this->db->select('IFNULL(t3.amount, t1.amount) as total');
$this->db->from('table1 as t1');
$this->db->join('table2 as t2', 't2.class = t1.class', 'LEFT');
$this->db->join('table3 as t3', 't3.student = t2.student AND t3.type = t1.type', 'LEFT');
// $this->db->get();
$lastquery = $this->db->last_query();

$this->db->select('SUM(TEMP.total) as total_amount');
$this->db->from('('.$lastquery.') as TEMP');
$result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: this is what i thought of. for now i'll  use it.

Comment: @romaltandel This answer is wrong, `get()` method will actually run the query. See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

If your mysql query is ok, please use this method for run complicated query like this.

```
$sql = "Your Query";
$qr = $this->db->query($sql);
return $qr->row();
```

If still you are not getting the output please check your subquery first inside the from clause.