# Any possible SQL injection vulnerability when using codeigniter active record?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-injection

Below is the code I use in my `Codeigniter` project for logging in an admin user

```
public function login()
{
    $usename = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', MD5($password));
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get('user');

    if($query->num_rows() == 1)
        return true; // login the user
    else
        return false; // user not found
}
```

When the query is echoed

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

it outputs something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (`user`) WHERE `username` = 'admin' 
    AND `password` = '5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99' LIMIT 1
```

Now when I input the password as `value)'; DROP TABLE user;--`, the query produced is :-

```
SELECT * FROM (`user`) WHERE `username` = 'admin' 
    AND `password` = 'c0b24ab68e0f79e23ebec36e36a5309f' LIMIT 1
```

So I guess it is pretty much safe from `sql injection` because `codeigniter` `active record` is automatically escaping the input data.

> **Edit based on comment**
>
> Now username is input with something like this `username'; DROP TABLE
>   user;--` then, the query produced is
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM (`user`) WHERE `username` = 'username\'; DROP TABLE user;--' 
>     AND `password` = '5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99' LIMIT 1
> ```
>
> So I guess it is escaping in that case also.

**But my question is, whether the above code is really sufficient enough to prevent all the possible sql injection attacks?**

Comment: In this case it's safe because you ***hash*** the input. CI may or may not be correctly escaping values in addition, but that's not the primary reason it's safe in this case.

Comment: Have you tried adding the drop table magic into the username field? What happens to that query?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter It really messes up the query. I didn't check that.  :)

Comment: @EatPeanutButter I think it is escaping in that case also. Plz check the edit

Comment: So that gives you more info about how CI is working behind the scenes.  You should also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615792/does-codeigniter-automatically-prevent-sql-injection