# Bug json decode API

Tags: php, json, api

I have a bug in my code.

My code is:

```
<?php $opts = array(

'http'=>array(

'method'=>"GET",

'max_redirects' => 100

));

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$url = 'https://fr.socialclub.rockstargames.com/member/m1ssashleex/games/gtav/snapmatic/ajax/search?Filter=MostRecent&page=1';

$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

$vresponse = json_decode($file);
?>
        <?php var_dump($vresponse); ?>
```

I testing all solutions, but i don't have success

error:

```
Message: file_get_contents(https://fr.socialclub.rockstargames.com/member/m1ssashleex/games/gtav/snapmatic/ajax/search?Filter=MostRecent&page=1): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 429
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: i'm not going to do that- the best way to ask a question on here is to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Your log message indicates a response code of: `429`, which, if you [look that up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429), means you were rate limited by the API server. **429 Too Many Requests**

Comment: The website looks to be live and productive. Why can we see PHP errors?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: I just tried... `SELECT * FROM devtimee__gaming__news WHERE titre LIKE '%' or 1=1;%' ORDER BY id DESC`

Comment: @Dharman Do you find that or?

Comment: To warn you about SQL injections.

Comment: Give me all info (go to Discord please: KilioZ#0001)

Comment: I don't have time to chat with you. My first recommendation would be to take the site down immediately. 2. Rewrite all your SQL queries to use prepared statements.

Comment: I use Framework PHP (CodeIgniter)

Comment: [Does CodeIgniter automatically prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615792/does-codeigniter-automatically-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: And now ? It's good the page ?

Answer (score 1):

1) The error message says `HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 429`. 429 is the error code for too many requests. The server does not deliver the content cause you have exceeded the rate limit.

2) The page you want to get does not work if you are not logged in on that site.

Comment: Oddly, this page asks me no auth for me

Comment: I assume you are logged in :) Try opening it in a private browsing tab.